# Swi-Prolog - how to delete the second element (if exist) in a list?

Tags: list, prolog

I need to write a program in swi-prolog that removes the second value of a list.
thanks!

Comment: (http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it could be as easy as:

```
remove2nd([], []).
remove2nd([X], [X]).
remove2nd([X, Y|Z], [X|Z]).
```

where you use it as:

```
remove2nd([1,2,3], X).
```

and gives you

```
X = [1, 3].
```

Comment: Excellent example to illustrate the need for the occurs-check: `remove2nd(L,L)`